# Can I take my drone into Australia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, australia, drones

I will live in Australia and would like to know if I can take my drone into the country. I have the invoice for the product, but I fear that the equipment will be barred at the airport. Are there any laws about it?

Answer (score 5):

I think your fears are just that .. fears.

The official CASA website: [Flying drones/remotely piloted aircraft in Australia](https://www.casa.gov.au/aircraft/landing-page/flying-drones-australia) has several sections about flying drones in Australia.  And (for example) under the section "How are you planning on flying your drone?" => "For fun" its states

> You don’t need approval to fly your drone for fun.

There are however other choices for if you are flying commercially depending on whether your drone is under/over 2kg.

And from a quick google of "import duty drone Australia" there are several hits coming back saying that that is 0%, so I wouldn't expect any hassle at Customs, especially as it's your personal belongings.

Comment: While importing drones is fine, there are restrictions on where you can fly them, including places like Sydney Harbour.  CASA has an app where you can easily check these.

Comment: Also, even if there’s no duty, one may be liable for GST (the local equivalent of VAT) depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score -1):

Supposedly if your drone batteries are properly stored in a Lipo Battery Fireproof bag you can get the batteries confiscated, as well as face a hefty fine, and might even be denied boarding onto the plane.

Here's a link to the bag: https://www.walmart.com/ip/Lipo-Battery-Fireproof-Bag-Storage-Guard-Safe-Charging-Holder-155mmx50mmx155mm/49312681

Comment: I suspect there is a "not" missing from that answer.

Comment: You're probably right. This doesn't make sense. Why would a properly stored battery be seized?

Comment: @MichaelHampton because the small print has slightly faded? Without naming names, there is a certain airport that always tries to stir up trouble for that (in my experience). And after a 30+ second staring contest they give in. I always take this power bank for my notebook, it's been to over 15 airports across the globe but staff at one airport likes to pick it out, every time.